# == between float and decimal in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal

```cs
static void Main()
{
     int a=10;
     Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToSingle(a)==Convert.ToDecimal(a));
}
```

Why does this code throw an error

> == cannot be applied to operands of type float and decimal

even if both the convert statements return 10?

Comment: John made the changes in the code. Is It fine now?

Comment: It looks like it should produce your error now without other unrelated errors, so yep! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like below.

```
bool Compare<T>(T x, T y) where T : class
{
    ...
}
```

So `x` and `y` should be of the same datatype. then only it can be compared. Decimal is 128 bits and single is 32 bits.

Decimal is [Decimal floating point](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Decimal) and Double is [Binary floating point](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/FloatingPoint).

Comment: But if you try ToSingle() and ToDouble() then there is no issue. Though single is 32 bits and double is 64 bits

Comment: @FurkhanShaikh please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Also
Convert.ToSingle():
Size - 4 bytes
Precision -7 digits

decimal.ToSingle():
Size - 16 bytes
Precision -28-29 decimal places

Although they might give the same output on display.
internally they are not same.

float and double are [floating binary point types](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/FloatingPoint) where as decimal is [floating decimal point type](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Decimal).

interesting article https://zetcode.com/lang/csharp/datatypes/
[image]

Comment: Then why ToSingle() and ToDouble() works?

Comment: float and double are [floating binary point types](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/FloatingPoint) where as decimal is [floating decimal point type](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Decimal).

Comment: @FurkhanShaikh: The reason comparing a `ToSingle()` result with a `ToDouble()` result works is that when the operands to `==` are mixed `float` and `double`, there is an automatic conversion from `float` to `double`. This is partly because the conversion never changes the value (every `float` is representable as a `double`) and is simple. There is no automatic conversion with `decimal` because that raises problems where the conversion may change the value, causing the result of `==` to be wrong.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The explanation is good and I request you to please give me any reference link of document or webpage where I can learn more about this.

Answer (score -2):

`ToSingle()` represents float number and `ToDecimal()` represents Double value that's why there precision does match

Comment: That's not the case I guess. If you try ToDouble() and ToSingle() then there is no issue.